# Reading updated values from a .config file

Tags: java, file, properties

I'm having some trouble when reading from a `.config` file in a Java application.

I have a module, let's call it Configuration_Reader that implements the next interface:

**Interface**

```
int getDelayValue();

int getRepValue();

...
```

For example, the getDelayValue() implementation is as follows:

**Implementation**

```
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
    new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/config/config.properties");
    props.load(fis);
    fis.close();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

            ...

   public int getDelayValue() {
      return getIntProperty("delayValue");
   }
```

There's no error nor exception when reading the value, but my issue is that **if I update the value** on the *config* file and call the `getDelayValue()` function again, it always returns the original value the property had when I launched the application. So, it is not updating (I assume it is not reading the file again) even if debugging I can see that the function is being called appropriately.

Any tips? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the config file to see the changes, i.e. this code

```
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/config/config.properties");
props.load(fis);
fis.close();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

needs to run again, after the config has changed.

If you're using Java 7 you can use a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to detect if the file has changed.

Another alternative would be to reload the config file every time a config value is accessed, but I wouldn't recommend this if the value is accessed frequently or concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: I forgot about the WatchService. Thanks mate ; )